# Why `\crefname` command generates error?

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, newtheorem

Does anybody know why `\crefname{thm}{AAAA}{AAAAs}` command generates error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=green]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\crefname{thm}{AAAA}{AAAAs}

\begin{document}
\section{Bla Bla}

\begin{thm}[My Theorem]\label{thm:b}
  This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is `Missing \begin{document}`, this usually means that you have used a command in the preamble that was supposed to be used inside of the document. This is also the case here: when you move the `\crefname` line after `\begin{document}` then the error disappears.

Comment: So, why when I change it to `\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}` in the preamble it works without any error? what is the mystery and role of `theorem` here?

Comment: It is indeed very strange. When you use a letter twice at the start of the name, like _aa_ or _QQ_, then it fails, otherwise it works fine. That counts as a bug I guess.